# How to grep/awk/sed for a random pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a log file that I am attempting to pull a string out of. The numerical string is randomly generated and so far all of my attempts to use grep/sed/awk have been unsuccessful.

I have an entry like the following:

```
"id":"30c962de-b448-40ac-ade8-da6a8f49ce88","title":
```

What I am trying to parse is the randomly generated portion of

```
30c962de-b448-40ac-ade8-da6a8f49ce88
```

Anyone have a quick and dirty method to get this to work?

Comment: This looks like it's from a longer JSON document. Could you share a bit more of the document's structure? It would be easy to pull it out with a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty like this?

```
$ grep -o -P '(?<=")[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}(?=")' input
30c962de-b448-40ac-ade8-da6a8f49ce88
```

Looks for any random `"30c962de-b448-40ac-ade8-da6a8f49ce88"` values with fixed length and dash `-` positions, enclosed in quotation marks, and prints it out. If you want to insist on the `"id":` part too, just add it to the leading quote condition `(?<=")`.

However if that's JSON or anything sane you should consider using an appropriate parser for that kind of data (like `jq` or whatever).

Comment: Or you could have it use the whole length between the quotes, but make it non greedy.

Comment: That works like a charm thanks!! It came from JSON but it is being logged to a log file and is being used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Another dirty trick using AWK on provided input.

```
data='"id":"30c962de-b448-40ac-ade8-da6a8f49ce88","title":
echo $data  | awk -F , '{ print $1}' | awk -F id:  '{print $1}' | awk  '{print $1}'
"30c962de-b448-40ac-ade8-da6a8f49ce88"
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is actually a JSON document, then using `jq` would pull the string out regardless of the formatting of the data:

```
jq -r '.document[2].part.id' file.json
```

This assumes that the `id` key is part of a `part` object, which is in turn part of a particular element in a `document` array at the top level of the JSON data structure.

Or, you could just extract *all* `id` values:

```
jq -r '.. | select(type=="object" and has("id")) | .id' file.json
```

Comment: I have not used jq so how would I use it to pull more than one value? Would I simply add multiple AND statements i.e. and has ("id" AND "status") or something similar??

Comment: @Kevin As I wrote in my comment to the question, we don't know what your document's structure looks like. A query in with `jq` (or any other JSON parser) relies on pulling out or examining specific keys/values in the document, at specific places. The way the query is written is highly dependent on the structure of the JSON document.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below mentioned sed command and it worked fine too

command: `sed 's/.*:"//1' filename|sed 's/".*//g'`

output

```
sed 's/.*:"//1' filename |sed 's/".*//g'

30c962de-b448-40ac-ade8-da6a8f49ce88
```

Answer (score 0):

using `awk`:

```
awk -F"[\":]" '{ print $5 }' infile
```